# Provide URI as cryptic hash or as human readable string?

Tags: usability

I am working on a tiny webservice on which a user can make his profile public.

By doing so a URI is generated that is changeable by the user. The system suggests a random generated streetname and house number for that URI.

For example: domain.com/user/Lincoln-Blvd-312

Is this a good idea or would you prefer a more technical approach like domain.com/user/bh21sl3?

To me the more human readable version is much more appealing but will it confuse the user? Are there other service doing the same?

Thanks for every comment

Comment: Are these physical addresses somewhat sensitive data? Do users have to be logged in to view whatever data is at that URL? Is there anything dangerous about publicly sharing the association between the user in the URL and the address in the URL? In other words, is there any reason to obscure it?

Comment: No there is no reason to obscure it. Data behind this link is willingly published. The only thought I had is, that it might be easier to communicate in public than a cryptic hash. Just in case (I know this sounds stupid) the user has no idea for this public URI.

Due to the fact that there will be no username on this service, this could not be used for suggesting

Comment: The street address solution is reminiscent of Geocities, which had a whole bunch of virtual suburbs.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like the approach that Stack Exchange has taken with their URL: it is comprised of **both a unique ID, and the title of the post**, however the title is purely to help the user and does not affect URL resolution.

This provides a unique way to resolve the URL (by ID), while still giving the user a preview of what the content of the page will be.

For example, the link to this post is

```
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131644/provide-uri-as-cryptic-hash-or-as-human-readable-string
```

- The first part, `https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131644`, is all the server needs to find the post.
- The last part, `/provide-uri-as-cryptic-hash-or-as-human-readable-string`, is purely for the user.

In other words, the following links all resolve to the first URL (the correct, complete URL):

```
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131644/provide-uri-as-cryptic-hash-or-as-human-readable-string
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131644
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131644/
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131644/strawberries-are-tasty
```

This also solves the problem of **collisions**. This prevents the user from writing another post with an existing title and running into issues because the link is not unique. I'm not sure exactly how the user creates and shares addresses or if they're required to be unique. So in your case, this may or may not be important.

Comment: Somehow this is similar to my idea, in which the housenumber would be an equivalent to an unique id

Comment: Yes, as long as your house number is guaranteed to be unique, meaning a user cannot have two different "shares/posts/instances" that both point to the same address. I don't know what these addresses represent, but if it's used as the unique ID, this means you must define what a unique address is, and ensure the URL is explicit enough to ensure it's unambiguous. For example, ensure these kinds of cases are covered (or ruled out by business logic): two addresses for a user in different rooms of the same apartment complex; two addresses that share the same name and number in different cities...

Comment: Yes I would ensure that it is unique

Answer (score 0):

You might find that Users prefer the behaviour employed by the likes of LinkedIn and Google+ (R.I.P.) whereby the profile can be made public and uses the User's name. That makes it very easy for the user and their friends to remember the URI, while also providing some level of authority to the user by making their name stand out in the system. The first John Smith would get the /john-smith URI, while the next would get john-smith-2 and so on. It depends on the system and the data associated with the User, would most Users want to be on public record associated with the system?